# javascript - calculate on change of values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onchange

In my html file I have 2select boxes and 4 input text boxes.

From the first select you can choose how many numbers (textboxes) would you like to use.
From the second select you can choose a mathematical operation (+,-,*,/)
According to users choice in first select, number of input boxes will appear.
Now you add numbers to these inputs and  based on what you have selected and what you have in inputs, the result should appear in a particular div.

Then, when I change anything the result should be updated.

This is what I have so far:

First select:

```
 <select id="quantity" name="qua" onchange="selectQuantity(this.value)">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
```

first select js:

```
 function selectQuantity(selectedValue){
    var e = document.getElementById("quantity");
    var quantity = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

 if ( quantity==='1') {
    $('#nt').fadeIn();
} else if ( quantity==='2') {
    $('#nt').fadeIn();
    $('#nt1').fadeIn();
} else if (  quantity==='3') {
    $('#nt').fadeIn();
    $('#nt1').fadeIn();
    $('#nt2').fadeIn();
} else { 
   $('#nt').fadeIn();
   $('#nt1').fadeIn();
   $('#nt2').fadeIn();
   $('#nt3').fadeIn()
 }
 }
```

Second select html:

```
 <select id="operation" name="ope" onchange="selectOperation(this.value)">
                <option value="+">+</option>
                <option value="-">-</option>
                <option value="*">*</option>
                <option value="/">/</option>
        </select>
```

Second select js:

```
 function selectOperation(selectedValue){
    var e = document.getElementById("operation");
    var operation = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
 }
```

Input text example:

```
 <input type="text" id="nt"  onchange="checkField(this.value)">
```

js:

```
 function checkField(val)
 {

 }
```

And the result div:

```
 <div id="result"></div>
```

So, where and how should I put my calculations to achieve this dynamicly updated result? To a separate function? 
All of my js functions are in separate js file.
Thank you.

-FIDDLE [example](http://jsfiddle.net/X7M8L/1/)

Comment: This is a typical question where making a jsFiddle would make everyone help you better/faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion:

```
function calculator() {
    var val1 = parseInt($('#quantity').val());
    var op = $('#operation').val();

    for (var i = 0; i < val1; i++) {
        var incr = i ? i : '';
        $('#nt' + incr).fadeIn();
    }
    var sum = 0;
    function values2() {
        var internalSum = 0;
        $('[id^="nt"').each(function () {
            internalSum += parseInt(this.value == '' ? 0 : this.value);
        });
        return internalSum;
    }

    switch (op) {
        case '+':
            sum = val1 + values2();
            break;
        case '-':
            sum = val1 - values2();
            break;
        case '*':
            sum = val1 * values2();
            break;
        case '/':
            sum = val1 / values2();
            break;
        default:
            console.log('Missing parameters');
    }
    $('#result').html(sum);
}
$('select, input').on('change', calculator);
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pXhcZ/1/)

Comment: That console.log statements are just for debugging?

Comment: @user2886091, just updated my answer after you added the other inputs. Please check the demo. About the `console.log();` you can actually ignore it/remove it. In case the operators input has a value that is not predicted in the switches it will fire.

Comment: I want to put that calculator() into a separate file. How can I ensure that it will be performed (except of <script type="text/javascript" src="js/calculate.js"></script>) please?

Comment: @user2886091, use this version (added a `domready` function around the event handler so it runs when page has loaded): http://jsfiddle.net/pXhcZ/2/